# How to make my own malloc thread safe and where to lock and unlock?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, thread-safety, malloc

I am implementing my own memory allocator but I would like to address thread safety. Here is my implementation of malloc:

```
pthread_mutex_t alloc_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; /*< Mutex for protecting the linked list */
void *malloc(size_t size)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&alloc_mutex);
size_t total_size = size + sizeof(struct mem_block);
size_t aligned_size = total_size;
if (total_size % 8 !=0) {
    aligned_size = (total_size / 8) * 8 + 8;
}

LOG("Allocation: request size = %zu, total size = %zu, aligned size = %zu\n", size, total_size, aligned_size);

struct mem_block *reused_block = reuse(aligned_size);
if(reused_block != NULL){
    return reused_block + 1;
}

int page_size = getpagesize();
size_t num_pages = aligned_size / page_size;
if(aligned_size % page_size != 0){
    num_pages++;
}
size_t region_size = num_pages * page_size;

struct mem_block *block = mmap(NULL, region_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

if(block == MAP_FAILED){
    perror("mmap");
    return NULL;
}

snprintf(block->name, 32, "Allocation %lu", g_allocations++);
block->size = region_size;
block->free = true;
block->region_id = g_regions++;

if(g_head == NULL && g_tail == NULL){
    block->next = NULL;
    block->prev = NULL;
    g_head = block;
     g_tail = block;
}
else {
    g_tail->next = block;
    block->prev = g_tail;
    block->next = NULL;
    g_tail = block;
}

split_block(block, aligned_size);
block->free = false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex);
return block+1;
}
```

My main question is: Where would I need to lock and unlock for my implementation to be thread safe? Because rn it is not.

Comment: You have two return statements without releasing the mutex. You will get deadlocks.

Comment: I just added it and my test program still says: timeout: failed to run command ‘tests/progs/thread-safety’. Could it be from anything outside of malloc? Obviously, that would be another problem for me ahah SO with one lock at the beginning and an unlock before every return my malloc would be 100% thread safe right?

Comment: Asking so that I can apply it to my other functions like free(), etc...

Comment: A simple way to quickly fix your existing code's non-standard `return`s [that do _not_ release the lock] is to use a `RETURN` macro: `#define RETURN(_val) do { pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex); return _val; } while (0)`. Then, replace (e.g.) `return NULL;` with `RETURN(NULL);` Do, this for all your other ones.

Comment: So that every time I return it automatically unlocks without me needing to call for it? That's great, I'll do that!

Comment: @Yohan as an added bonus, that macro leaves a brilliant aura of mystery to the future readers of your code, as now they get to hunt down a macro to find out whether you're actually releasing the locks the code has no obvious outward appearance of actually doing. Macros are like Swiss Army Nives with 40-blades: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. There's a time and a place, and frankly, this is neither.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I guess it'd be more useful somewhere else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement two functions, one called 'malloc_impl' with the main functionality and another one called 'malloc' which locks the mutex, calls 'malloc_impl' and unlocks it.

Another solution would be to use 'goto'. Depending on the case, jump to the specific label, in that way, you have to specify the unlock only once.

Example:

```
void *block = NULL;

if (err_cond) 
    goto fail;

if (cond) 
    goto done;

// do some other stuff

goto done;

fail:
    block = NULL;
done:
    unlock_mutex();
    return block;
```

p.s. yes, gotos are evil, but sometimes very (very) useful.